# Flex 4 - BlazeDS - Spring - Hibernate: how to "call" client when some server treatments are finished?

Tags: hibernate, spring, flex4, blazeds

This is what I would like to do: in my database, there are some elements associated with the treatment delay. From the Flex client, I want to alert when these elements treatement are finished. These elements are knows for all clients.

So, what is the best architecture for that (client side and server side) ?

Thank you so much,

regards

Anthony

Answer (score 0):

You can use BlazeDS Messaging for that.  Check out the [Messaging samples in Tour de Flex](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-archive/flex/tourdeflex/web/#sampleId=13920;illustIndex=0;docIndex=0) for some examples.